# How do I load a plist file from disk as a NSDictionary on iOS?

Tags: ios, plist, nsdictionary

I want to load the plist file from disk (documents, application cache, ...) not from a resource bundle.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can load a plist from any accessible file path with [-initWithContentsOfFile:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/initWithContentsOfFile%3a) or [+dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithContentsOfFile%3a)

Load a plist from a file, and create the file if it did not exist:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                    NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
self.plistFile = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]
                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"example.plist"];

self.plist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFile];
if (!plist) {
    self.plist = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [plist writeToFile:plistFile atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: Note that the Plist's root object must be a dictionary. If the root object is an array, you should use [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFile];

Answer (score 28):

A little cleaner:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plistName" ofType:@"plist"]; 
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Comment: depends on the directory, documentdirectory != resource path

Answer (score 2):

It's always good to have a Swift version. It load a plist from the bundle.

```
if let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "plistName", ofType: "plist") {
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath)
}
```