# Save multiple sets of data locally on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

We have a basic application that uses a storyboard for all the 'pages'. Each page has basic product info and there is a contact form. It's used at trade shows, usually with an internet connection, therefore the contact form is just a UIWebView.

The next event has no internet available and I need to set up the contact / details form to work offline and store the info on the device (iPad), with a page to also retrieve it. I'm not overly experienced with iOS (but I'm proficient in programming knowledge), so any ideas or pointers to tutorials would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your data in the form of a plist.

Later you can load your data from the plist using the code here.

[Load NSDictionary from plist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5355537/1891327)

Answer (score 0):

Plist can be helpfull but you are using webview so you cannot put plist's data to webview. so you need to cache your pages. that can be enought for your situation: [iOS Cache a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609635/ios-cache-a-uiwebview) 
Or this approach is better to use [UIWebView webpage caching for offline viewing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826820/uiwebview-webpage-caching-for-offline-viewing)